# What does the signature of this bilinear form on the representation algebra k[G] tell about representations?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field. There is a symmetric bilinear form
$$
\langle f,h\rangle =\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g)h(g^{-1})
$$
on the group algebra $k[G]$. If I am not mistaken, this form should be non-degenerate.

If $k=\mathbb{C}$ or $k=\mathbb{R}$, there is a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_bilinear_form#Signature_and_Sylvester.27s_law_of_inertia) $(p,q)$ for this form.

Is there a representation theoretic interpretation for the signature? (E.g. does it count some type of representation, etc.?)

Comment: The quadratic space $k\left[G\right]$ (equipped with this bilinear form) is the orthogonal direct sum of its subspaces of the form $\left<g,g^{-1}\right>$ for $g \in G$ (except that some of these subspaces will be identical, and thus need to be removed for the direct sum to be actually direct). These subspaces are $1$-dimensional when $g = g^{-1}$, and $2$-dimensional otherwise. The bilinear form is positive-definite in the former case, and indefinite in the latter. So the signature should be easily computable from the number of involutions in $G$.